# How to close a lot of open ports on home laptop

Tags: windows-7, internet, port, nmap

I scanned my laptop for open ports. Nmap found about 1000+ open ports with unknown services. I tried to create rules in the Windows firewall that closed these ports, but this did not help. Also I used other programms for close that ports and it also didn't help. How can I close them?

[image]

Comment: You will probably find that many of these ports are meant to be open. Run `netstat -ab` to list the owning processes. See [Netstat - TCP/IP network connections - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/netstat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These ports are not open. These are "unknown" (in the second column). You don't need to close them. Please see [*Nmap scan produces all “unknown”*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/21544).

Fragments of two answers published there:

> The problem is with Windows and scanning the local machine. Nmap on Windows does not work the same way as it does on Linux due to differences in how the NIC is accessed. It is not actually connecting to each port from a separate process, but is connecting to itself.

> This output is expected when scanning from Windows to localhost (127.0.0.1, ::1, or an IP address that belongs to the scanning system itself), but only for Nmap versions released prior to July 2016. Nmap 7.25BETA1 added Windows localhost scanning with the use of the new Npcap packet capture library, so this will not be an issue any more.

Comment: So I can not worry about these "unknown" ports?

Comment: @h4cktivist Affirmative.